# Generate mongoose DTO for MEAN application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and node and I am building an application using the MEAN stack (Mongo ExpressJS AngularJS Node).

I have built a lot of APIs in the past using asp.net WebAPI, and I can't find any documentation on the use of DTO or View Models, in order to reduce the volume of JSON transfered back and forth between my server and my front end.

My application is about a survey that users fill online. Each answers is then used to produce a score by user.

My models:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, trim: true,default: '', match: [/.+\@.+\..+/,'']},
    status: {type: String},
    token:{type: String, default: crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex')},
    score: {
        managementExperience: {type: Number},
        managementSkills: {type: Number},
        relevantKnowledge: {type: Number},
        commitment: {type: Number},
        acceptanceOfChange: {type: Number},
        age: {type: Number},
        totalScore: {type: Number}
    },
    answers: [
        {
            optionId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}
        }
    ]
});

var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    client_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' },
    creationDate:{type: Date,default: Date.now},
    title: {type: String, trim: true},
    surveyVersion: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SurveyVersion' },
    users:[UserSchema]
});
```

The survey screen itself works, but when it comes to produce a dashboard of the results, I would like to send a DTO and not the whole SurveySchema, like this model:

```
var SurveySchemaLight = new Schema({
    client_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' },
    creationDate:{type: Date,default: Date.now},
    title: {type: String, trim: true},
    users:[{
        email: {type: String, trim: true,default: '', match: [/.+\@.+\..+/,'']},
        status: {type: String}
    }]
});
```

In .Net world I would have this model to have a constructor that takes as parameters an instance of SurveySchema, but I can't find a way to make it work.

I also tried to have both Schemas linked to the same collection in mongodb:

```
mongoose.model('Survey', SurveySchema);
mongoose.model('SurveyLight', SurveySchemaLight, 'surveys');
```

But when I run the following query on SurveyLight schema, I still have all the fields from Survey returned:

```
SurveyLight.find({'client_id': req.params.clientID}).exec(function(err, surveyList){
        res.json(surveyList);
    });
```

What would be the best practices to have a DTO/View Model mechanism in my stack?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "mongoose" and MongoDB queries in general, you just "project" the fields you require in your output, ignoring others you do not want.

As a self contained example:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var childSchema = new Schema({
  "longName": String,
  "email": String,
  "status": String
})

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String,
  "longDescription": String,
  "children": [childSchema]
})

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Parent = mongoose.model( 'Parent', parentSchema );

async.waterfall(
  [
    // remove any samples
    function(callback) {
      Parent.remove({},function(err,res) {
        callback(err)
      });
    },

    // insert some test data
    function(callback) {
      Parent.create(
        {
          "name": "Bill",
          "longDescription": "Something we don't want to see",
          "children": [
            { "longName": "don't want", "email": "a@example.com", "status": "A" },
            { "longName": "don't want", "email": "b@example.com", "status": "B" }
          ]
        },
        function(err,doc) {
          console.log( doc );
          callback(err,doc);
        }
      )
    },

    // Fetch just the fields we want
    function(doc,callback) {
      Parent.find({},"name children.email children.status", callback);
    }
  ],

  // Ouput results
  function(err,result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    process.exit();
  }
);
```

Which outputs in the following form:

```
// The original form of the documents
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'Bill',
  longDescription: 'Something we don\'t want to see',
  _id: 5598b6bad439a31807bfe746,
  children:
   [ { longName: 'don\'t want',
       email: 'a@example.com',
       status: 'A',
       _id: 5598b6bad439a31807bfe748 },
     { longName: 'don\'t want',
       email: 'b@example.com',
       status: 'B',
       _id: 5598b6bad439a31807bfe747 } ] }

// The output document with just selected fields
[ { _id: 5598b6bad439a31807bfe746,
    name: 'Bill',
    children:
     [ { email: 'a@example.com', status: 'A' },
       { email: 'b@example.com', status: 'B' } ] } ]
```

If you want to "exclude" fields rather than name them all explicitly then prefix with `-` as in

```
"-longName -children.logDescription"
```

But you cannot "mix" the two terms, with the exception of `"-_id"`

Comment: Thanks Blakes, I did not know this syntax to list the fields to output!

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript world, you should try to approach this problem from a functional programming perspective. You have some data, you want to return a subset of this data. You don't need a separate model definition, you just need a map/filter function.

e.g.

```
SurveyLight.find({'client_id': req.params.clientID}).exec(function(err, surveyList){
        var parsedSurveyList = surveyList.map(function(survey){
          survey.users = survey.users.map(function(user){
            return {email: user.email, status: user.status};
          });
          return survey;  
        });
        res.json(parsedSurveyList);
    });
```

You can make this a lot better by using popular functional libraries such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I was more asking if a mongoose mechanism could be used to avoid this kind of code.